# How to access views within ListView rows?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView that is set up with an ArrayAdapter. The adapter gives each row of the ListView a CheckBox with some text. The adapter is based on Strings and basically just creates a CheckBox and sets its text to the corresponding String. Outside of the ListView there is a Switch that when turned on should check all the CheckBoxes in the ListView. I am having difficulty being able to access the CheckBoxes within each row of the ListView in the method that handles the Switch being clicked. I tried using getItemAtPosition(), but as far as I can tell it only gives me the String that is the CheckBox's text. Can someone please provide some help on how to do this?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

To get the view for list item use `getChildAt()` on the list and then you can call `findViewById()` on the view to get the checkbox, however this will only work for views that are visible in the list.

To make your life easier create a custom array adapter, with a custom class. The class should have a boolean field like `isChecked` and in `getView()` set the checkbox to `checked` or `unchecked` depending the value of the `isChecked` field, then you can use `getItem()` to retrieve the class of list item you want to change the value of `isChecked` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.

Comment: getChildAt seemingly only works for the views that are visible. Can I also use it for the views that aren't visible?

Comment: See my updated answer above, any queries just reply on comment.